# Nonliner Regression Toolbox in Matlab (nlinfit)

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression

Do anyone know which algorithm and objective function for nonlinear regression MATLAB toolbox? I am looking at MATLAB website but it did not provide the information.

Answer (score 0):

The `Algorithms` and `References` section at the end of the doc for [nlinfit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) lists the algorithms and gives reference to them.

The objective function is (obviously?) different depending on the problem being solved.