# Nonliner Regression Toolbox in Matlab (nlnfit)

Tags: matlab

Do anyone know which algorithm and objective function for nonlinear regression MATLAB toolbox? I am looking at MATLAB website but it did not provide the information.

Comment: This question will most likely be off topic on [SO] as well, I suspect.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe MATLAB's tech support or a tutorial they offer or a MATLAB-based textbook might help. I don't even understand your question. But questions about software, toolboxes, functions, etc. are off topic here, & asking for a tool, etc. is a listed reason for voting off topic on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nonliner Regression Toolbox in Matlab (nlinfit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431061/nonliner-regression-toolbox-in-matlab-nlinfit)